# Multidimensional JSON Array Construction?

Tags: json

I need to create a **multidimensional** **JSON array** that stores information in the following manner:

```
Teams{
   Team1:Services{
      ServiceName:Service1
      ServiceName:Service2,
      ServiceName:Service3
   }
   etc..
}
```

I'm not sure if I am listing the correct notation there, but I am just trying to represent the data structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `Teams` is the root level, maybe something like this:

```
{
  teams: [
    {
      name: 'Team1',
      serviceNames: ['Service1', 'Service2' ...]
    }
  ]
}
```

I left out the associative bit from services (i.e. `ServiceName`) because they're all the same, so you may as well use an array for clarity.

I also made everything camelcase because that is generally the convention for JSON.

Comment: you're welcome. there's a fairly indepth explanation of how json works here - http://www.w3schools.com/json/

also, just a reminder to accept the correct answer :)